# Java "Asteroids" Like Game - Slowing Down Ship

Tags: java, swing

So I have a Java swing application wherein there is a spaceship that gets the angle of rotation and then accelerates in that direction (rotates on its on axis and moves where the front of the ship is). The thing I was having trouble with was getting the ship to decelerate when it points in the opposite direction from its previous direction.

[What Happens and what I need to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP8rL.gif)

If you look at the image, you'll see that when I try to compensate for my velocity by turning in the completely opposite direction, the speed increases, and what I need to do is have a way to decrease the speed if the ship is compensating for its previous speed.

Example1:

```
import java.util.Set;

/**
* Created by griffin on 12/7/2015.
*/
public class Example1 extends JPanel {

public enum Input {
    ROTATE_LEFT,
    ROTATE_RIGHT,
    UP,
    DOWN
}

private final int B_WIDTH = 640;
private final int B_HEIGHT = 480;
private Set<Input> inputs;

Ship player = new Ship(320, 240);

public Example1() {
    initExample1();
}

private void initExample1() {
    inputs = new HashSet<>(25);
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));

    addKeyBinding("rotate-left", KeyEvent.VK_A, Input.ROTATE_LEFT);
    addKeyBinding("rotate-right", KeyEvent.VK_D, Input.ROTATE_RIGHT);
    addKeyBinding("up", KeyEvent.VK_W, Input.UP);
    addKeyBinding("down", KeyEvent.VK_S, Input.DOWN);

    Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            if (inputs.contains(Input.ROTATE_LEFT)) {
                player.angle -= 5;
            }

            if (inputs.contains(Input.UP)) {

                player.thrust = true;
                player.moveForwards();
            }
            else
                player.moveForwards();

            if (inputs.contains(Input.ROTATE_RIGHT)) {
                player.angle += 5;
            }

            player.checkAngle();
            player.screenWrap();

            repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.drawString("Speed " + (int) player.speed, 15, 15);
    AffineTransform old = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(player.x, player.y);
    old.rotate(Math.toRadians(player.angle), player.getWidth() / 2, player.getHeight() / 2);
    g2d.setTransform(old);
    g2d.drawImage(player.ship, 0, 0, this);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

private void addKeyBinding(String name, int keyCode, Input input) {
    InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false), name + ".pressed");
    actionMap.put(name + ".pressed", new InputAction(input, true));

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true), name + ".released");
    actionMap.put(name + ".released", new InputAction(input, false));
}

private class InputAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Input input;
    private boolean pressed;

    public InputAction(Input input, boolean pressed) {
        this.input = input;
        this.pressed = pressed;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (pressed) {
            inputs.add(input);
        } else {
            inputs.remove(input);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ship:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

/**
* Created by griffin on 12/7/2015.
*/
public class Ship {
float directionX, directionY;
boolean thrust = false;
int x, y;
float speed = 1;
int angle = 0, vAngle = 0;

BufferedImage ship;
private String path = "rocketc.png";

public Ship(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    getImage();
}

private void getImage() {
    try {
        ship = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int getWidth() {
    return ship.getWidth();
}

public int getHeight() {
    return ship.getHeight();
}

public void moveForwards() {

    directionX = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(vAngle))) * speed;
    directionY = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(vAngle))) * speed;

    if (thrust) {
        speed++;

        vAngle = angle;
        thrust = false;
    }

    x -= directionX;
    y -= directionY;

}

    public void checkAngle () {

        if (angle > 360) {
            angle = 0;
        }
        if (angle < 0) {
            angle = 360;
        }
    }


    public void screenWrap () {
        if (x > 640) {
            x = 0;
        }

        if (x < 0) {
            x = 640;
        }

        if (y > 480) {
            y = 0;
        }

        if (y < 0) {
            y = 480;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the direction of the player should effect the amount of delta applied to the speed of the player.  That is, if they are turned 180 degrees in the opposite direction of the thrust, then you need to reduce the speed, instead of increasing it.  If they turned 90 degrees, then you need to reduce the speed in one direction, while increasing the speed in the new direction ... and there is about where my head implodes

Comment: Yes it is quite hard to figure out. I have hit a wall and am unsure how to figure this out...

Comment: You're going to need to delve into some basic(?) physics ... hence the reason my head imploded

Comment: Would you please clarify? Any resources or things to recommend? I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I've been trying to look up vector maths, but it's way over my head

Answer (score 2):

You've probably figured this out by now, but you're not setting `player.thrust` back to `false` when you're checking if the up key is pressed.

```
if (inputs.contains(Input.UP)) {
    player.thrust = true;
    player.moveForwards();
}
else{
    player.thrust = false; // added this line
    player.moveForwards();
}
```

Also, if you want drag (that is, deceleration when the up key is not pressed), in `Ship.moveForwards()` you can decrement `speed`:

```
if (thrust) {
    speed++;

    vAngle = angle;
    thrust = false;
}
else{ // added this block
    speed--;
}
```

You can fiddle with incrementing / decrementing `speed` by different values to get different acceleration / drag.